# Add vertical lines to a graph

Tags: r, graph

I'm wanting to add vertical dotted/dashed on top of my time series graph at even intervals.

Would I put an extra command in the abline arguments or is there another way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [grid](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/graphics/html/grid.html):

> **nx, ny** - number of cells of the grid in x and y direction. When NULL, as per default, the grid aligns with the tick marks on the
>   corresponding default axis (i.e., tickmarks as computed by axTicks).
>   When NA, no grid lines are drawn in the corresponding direction.

Example:

```
plot(1:5)
grid(nx = NULL, ny = NA)
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You can supply vector arguments for `v` parameter in `abline()` to plot multiple lines. `lty` parameter lets you specify line type and also can be a vector.
Quick example:

```
x=1:16
y=2*x+rnorm(16)
plot(x,y,type='b')
abline(v=.3+1:16,lty=rep(c(3,4),times = 8))
```

[image]